# Construct a square given one side

Tags: geometry

I have two points
$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$

I want to calculate the other two points $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$ of the square.

I have attached the image for explanation.

[image]

All 4 sides should be equal and have same angle.

Comment: [Just for your information](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures), about signing one's posts.

Comment: there's more than one solution to this...  you might simply construct a square on the given side...

Comment: Yes, its a square. Let me edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 solutions are:

1. $P_3 =(x_1+(y_2-y_1),y_1-(x_2-x_1))$, $P_4 =(x_2+(y_2-y_1),y_2-(x_2-x_1))$; and
2. $P_3'=(x_1-(y_2-y_1),y_1+(x_2-x_1))$, $P_4'=(x_2-(y_2-y_1),y_2+(x_2-x_1))$.

Thee two solutions are of course mirror images across the line extended through $x_1-x_2$. Performing the dot-product of $(P_2-P_1)$ with $(P_3-P_1)$ readily verifies that they two vectors form a $90$ degree angle. The remaining angles are quickly seen to also be $90$ degrees from inspection.